# Help converting a .bat to a .sh

Tags: macos, shell, batch

I need a little help converting a short script from .bat to .sh

```
:convertfile
@IF %1 == "" GOTO end
imf_copy -p %1 "%~d1%~p1%~n1.map"
@SHIFT
@GOTO convertfile
:end
@ECHO.
@ECHO Done!
@pause
```

`imf_copy` is a Maya Plugin.  Basically its function is to convert .tiff files into .map files.  A .map file basically works in conjunction with Maya's mental ray to create an image map which will only load the images that are within the active camera's view.

I found it for PC but can't find its Mac OS X counterpart.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
#!/bin/bash

# run imf_copy <file> <file with extension changed to .map>
# for every file passed on the command line
for arg in "$@"; do
    imf_copy -p "$arg" "${arg%.*}.map"
done

echo ''
echo 'Done!'

# consider removing this
read
```

This is a literal translation.

You probably don't really want the `read` line, which was probably only there so that if the DOS batch script started a new window, the window would stay open until the user pressed Enter.